# Parse value from JSON to url

Tags: html, json

I created a little script that creates a url from a textbox value like this:

```
<input id="cod_meio" name="cod_meio" type="text" value="">
<input id="inspecionar" name="inspecionar" onclick="location.href='http://hyves.worldofalice.com/jsonp.php?m='+ document.getElementById('cod_meio').value;" type="button" value="inspecionar">
```

This will open the URL in a new window, but that is not what I want! Can I get a string from the generated JSON? and put that again in another url?

```
addMessage("bot", {"url":false,"messages":[{"fontFamily":"Arial","fontColor":"008000","fontWeight":"normal","body":"Hi :D"}]});
```

Only the body message for example, and put that after http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=nl&q=

Is this possible and is someone able to help me?

Comment: I think you are looking for json.parse()

Comment: In the `onclick` you have to retrieve the JSON message with AJAX(use jQuery if possible, it will make your life easier). Then parse the message as @CodeLover suggests, and than you can create the google URL. Maybe more description would help.

Comment: And if you want it to be automatically read by translate.google than you can add an `iframe` to your page and set its url dynamically with javascript by adding the text from JSON. Not sure if it will work, I haven't tried it.

Comment: Okay thanks! The point is that I want to let Google read the text (body) from the generated JSON. (Google's output is mp3) Can you give a code example?